# copy values from one sheet to another when a specific condition is true

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am absolute beginner and facing the following problem.

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets, “tab1” and “tab2”

Now I would like to copy the a values from a range or cell from “tab1” to “tab2” depending on the condition in A9

I have tried the following script but it keeps copying the values regardless the condition in A9 is not met.

What I am doing wrong here ?

```
function copyIf() {
    source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tab1");
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tab2");

    var condition   = source.getRange('A9').getValue();

    if (condition == "mon") {
        source.getRange('A2').copyTo(destination.getRange('D11'));
      source.getRange('A5').copyTo(destination.getRange('D5'));
    }
}
```

---

Hello guys, thank you for the quick help, I am sorry for not being precise, I have created a new example sheet and adapted the code you provided me accordingly. Basically it works fine but I still have a small issue.

``function copyIf() {

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheetByName("tab1");
var destination = ss.getSheetByName("tab2");
var condition = source.getRange('A9').getValue();
if (condition == "mon") { 
source.getRange('B14').copyTo(destination.getRange('B5'));
source.getRange('B15').copyTo(destination.getRange('C5'));
```

}
}

The source range B14 and B15 contains a formula to sum up the total from E14:F14, E15:F15

The goal is to copy the Value from B14 and B15 to the second sheet ( tab2, B5 and C5 ) as long as the condition is met ( Tab1, A9=mon ), else nothing should be changed

This is working fine except the target ( tab2, B5 and C5 ) reflects the formula and not the value

I am sure it is just a tiny issue but couldn't figure it out

Hier is the link to the test sheet :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12X4CPa6qbb2nRPqPthI0F0_fszaga4jTIQ6ouUjZ6Yk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should add the google-app-script tag to this question.

I copied your code, set a sheet up as you described, added `var` to the source variable declaration, and it worked as you say you intended. The "cleaned" code is:

```
function copyIf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("tab1"); 
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("tab2");
  var condition = source.getRange('A9').getValue();
  if (condition == "mon") {  
    source.getRange('A2').copyTo(destination.getRange('D11'));
    source.getRange('A5').copyTo(destination.getRange('D5'));
  } 
}
```

I also made a new variable called `ss` in order to reduce your API calls by 1 (not exactly crucial here but good practise).

If this does not resolve your issue, please edit your original post to include more information and perhaps give a link to a dummy spreadsheet.

I would have suggested this via a comment only but cannot comment with less than 50 reputation...

Comment: Answer edited in response to the suggested edits in OPs question.